# selectonemenu inside table in jsf2

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a table with 2 selectOneMenu components.

I would like that once a record was chosen in the first selectOneMenu component it will update the other selectOneMenu with Ajax in the same row.

My table:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myInfo}" var="myInfo">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Group</f:facet>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myInfo.myInfoType.code}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myList}" />
            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{myBean.refershNames}" render="myNames"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="myNames" value="#{myInfo.myInfoType.secondCode}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.mySecondList}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
<p:dataTable>
```

In the bean I have:

```
List<SelectItem> myList,mySecondList;

public void refershNames(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    //how can I retrieve the selected item and update the relevant record?
}
```

How can I do it with Ajax? I am using JSF2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the datatable value in [`DataModel<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) so that you can obtain the `myInfo` object in question by [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29). So,

```
DataModel<MyInfo> myInfoModel; // +getter

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    myInfo = myInfoDAO.list();
    myInfoModel = new ListDataModel<MyInfo>(myInfo);
}
```

with

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.myInfoModel}" var="myInfo">
```

and

```
public void refreshNames(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    MyInfo myInfo = myInfoModel.getRowData();
    // Get code and update secondCode.
}
```

---

**Update** as per the comments, here is the testcase I created after you told that it didn't work. It worked for me with Mojarra 2.0.3 on both Tomcat 7.0.5 and Glassfish 3.0.1.

`com.example.Item`

```
public class Item {

    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    // Generate public getters/setters.    
}
```

`com.example.Bean`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Item> items;
    private DataModel<Item> model;
    private List<String> list;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = Arrays.asList(new Item(), new Item(), new Item());
        model = new ListDataModel<Item>(items);
        list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    }

    public void change(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
        Item item = model.getRowData();
        item.setValue2(item.getValue1());
    }

    public DataModel<Item> getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

`test.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.value1}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="select..." itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" />
                <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{bean.change}" render="list2" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="list2" value="#{item.value2}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="select..." itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This testcase proves that whenever you change a dropdown value in the 1st column, then the dropdown value in the 2nd column in the same row will be reflected to retrieve the same value.

Comment: But how will I refresh only the select item in the same row?

Comment: but wouldnt it render all the select one item in all the table?

Comment: No, you specified a relative identifier. Each row has a parent identifier of the row index. Or did it not work that way for you?

Comment: It doesn't help. it returns only the original value and not the new selected value

Comment: Isn't it been overridden by some reload in the getter during render response?

Comment: I saw that after clicking it invokes again the getter of the table! why is it?

Comment: Is that a problem? Is the getter doing more than only returning the data? That job should then not be done in the getter.

Comment: it just returns the data. but I see that it returns the original data ignoring the new selected value although I have <f:ajax>

Comment: I created a local testcase and it just works (Mojarra 2.0.3). Your problem lies somewhere else. Do you want me to post the full code which I used for the testcase?

Comment: See answer update. Note that I now realize that you're using PrimeFaces. You might need to use `<p:ajax>` instead. Also note that the item value has to implement `equals()` properly, for the case that it's not a standard type (String, Number, Boolean).

Comment: Impossible for me to use DataModel<Item> : The type DataModel is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Item>. Deprecated ?!

Comment: @Quentin: The generic type was introduced in JSF 2.0. Apparently you're still using JSF 1.x. See also the javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and after a lot of trial and error this worked for me

```
<p:column style="width:50%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Criteria" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{option.predefinedMessageId}"
                        valueChangeListener="#{predefinedMessageBean.predefinedMessageChangeListener}">
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{campaignRecipientCriteriaBean.messages}"
                            var="predef" itemLabel="#{predef.fieldName}"
                            itemValue="#{predef.predefinedMessageId}" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="optionsList"/>

                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>


                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Options" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputPanel id="optionsList">
                    <h:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{option.predefinedMessageOptionId}">
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{predefinedMessageBean.emptyOptionBeansList}"
                            var="predef" itemLabel="#{predef.optionCaption}"
                            itemValue="#{predef.predefinedMessageOptionId}" />

                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:column>
```

valuechangelistener is

```
public void predefinedMessageChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e)
{

        getPredefinedMessageOptions(Integer.parseInt(e.getNewValue().toString()));


}
```

This is simple and works perfectly for me , as the message that i choose in the first column updates the options in the second column and its done through ajax. But then again, i m still learning and alot of my knowledge of jsf is from material from @BalusC blog :), so if this approach has some flaws, please lemme know.